# Crud with angularjs and http service

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5.1

I am starting to learn angularjs, so far i can create update delete withoud using services. I am trying to take it to the next level: Ive created a service page that looks like this:

```
app.factory('MainService', function($http) { 

    var getFeaturesFromServer = function() {
        return $http.get('restfullfeatures/features');
    }


    var deleteFeature = function(id) {
        return $http.post('restfullfeatures/delete', {'id': id});
    }

    var createFeature = function(feature) {
        return $http.post('restfullfeatures/create', {'title': feature.title, 'description': feature.description});
    }

    return {
        getHello : getHello,
        getFeatures: getFeaturesFromServer,
        deleteFeature: deleteFeature,
        createFeature: createFeature
    }

});
```

and my add function in controller looks like this:

```
$scope.add = function(){

        MainService.createFeature($scope.formFeature)

            .then(function(response) {
                console.log('feature created',response.data);
                $scope.features.push($scope.formFeature);
                $scope.formFeature = {};
            }, function(error) {
                alert('error',error);

        });

    };
```

And this is my postCreate function:

```
public function postCreate()

{
    \App\Feature::create(
        ['title' => \Input::get('title'), 
        'description' => \Input::get('description')
        ]);

    return ['success' => true];

}
```

I have a table in my database called features, so basically what i am trying to do is add a new feature to my table using angularjs, my controller doesnt seem to recognize formFeature all i get is 'undefined' then i get the error: Cannot read property of type undefined, but I am using it in my delete function and it works perfectly, what did i miss here??

Comment: From your code we can see that ```formFeature``` is defined in the return from server at ```createFeature```. Do you initialize it when the relative controller gets created?

Comment: How can i initialize it ?? Please bear with me I am new to all this. Thank you

Comment: At the beginning of the Controller body just do ```$scope.formFeature = {};```. Unfortunately I suspect there's something else going on...

Comment: omg it works!! Thank youu very much

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked

Answer (score 0):

**Factory**

So when creating a factory for CRUD, try to lay out your factory like the example below. The example is some code I wrote for a project each call willl do a different thing, the idea is that you add a method that you can instantiate when you add the factory to your controller. (note: don't use `$rootScope` for session)

```
.factory('Chats', function ($http, $rootScope, $stateParams) {

  return {
    all: function () {
      return $http.get('http://your_ip/chats', { params: { user_id: $rootScope.session } })
    },
    get: function () {
      return $http.get('http://your_ip/chat', { params: { user_id: $rootScope.session, chat_id: $stateParams.idchat } })
    },
    add: function (id) {
      return $http.post('http://your_ip/newChat', { params: {idfriends:id}})
    }
  };
});
```

**Controller**

when you instantiate this in your controller your looking at something like this

```
.controller('ChatsCtrl', function ($scope, Chats) {

  Chats.all().success(function (response) {
    $scope.chats = response;
  });
  $scope.getChat = function (id) {
    Chats.get().success(function (response) { })
  };

  $scope.addChat = function (id) {
    Chats.add(id).success(function (response) { })
  };
})
```

`$scope.remove` and `$scope.addChat` and linked to buttons that will execute on click and `$scope.chats` is bound to the page via an ng-repeat.

**Conclusion**

Clean up your factories to look like this and you can easily write a series of reusable methods that are easy to instantiate in your controller.